# iOS: UIWebViewDelegate methods/functions with CustomWebView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

`UIWebViewDelegate` methods/functions are not being called from custom web view`.

Code I've tried:

```
class CustomWebView: UIWebView, UIWebViewDelegate {


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // Web view delegate method - not called upon web view load
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("webViewDidFinishLoad")
    }

   /*
   // tried this also
   override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    self.delegate = self
   }
   */
}
```

// View controller code

```
class WebControllerVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
   @IBOutlet weak var wvWebView: CustomWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wvWebView.delegate = self
        wvWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil) // htmlString is string variable with data in HTML format 
    }

}
```

I tried to look around following SO Posts, but can't see solution for custom web view.

- [UIWebViewDelegate methods not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646876/uiwebviewdelegate-methods-not-getting-called)
- [ShouldStartLoad of custom UIWebViewDelegate not being called when UIWebView request starts loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404152/shouldstartload-of-custom-uiwebviewdelegate-not-being-called-when-uiwebview-requ)
- [UiWebView delegate methods not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219916/uiwebview-delegate-methods-not-getting-called?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [uiwebviewdelegate not called from non-visible uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166399/uiwebviewdelegate-not-called-from-non-visible-uiwebview)

Comment: Are you sure that initializer is being called? Have you set your breakpoint? I've done something similar to this but set myself as delegate in `viewDidLoad`. Also, the delegate function `webViewDidFinishLoad` will only get called if you send your `webview` it a particular urlRequest to render, where are you doing that?

Comment: Just noticed that you are using UIWebView and not a UIViewController class with a webView. Try adding it to `initWithFrame` to make sure that delegate is set no matter which initializer is used. But I think your main problem is not delegate being set but the fact you are not doing any loading of html or request.

Comment: but where are you calling `loadRequest(_:)` or `loadHTMLString(_:)` ? You have to load web content to get your delegate to call its methods pertaining to the loading of web content

Comment: Can you show code for the initialization of `webView`in `ViewController` and then the loading of the html? Maybe there is something in there that needs to change.

Comment: I think you will have to find another method, Personally I would make the `viewcontroller` the delegate and not the `webView` itself. I just found in apple documentation they specifically say under class reference for `UIWebView` under `Subclassing Notes` not to subclass it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: Cmon man, You set its delegate to the view controller after its initialized. So of course the delegate functions won't be called in the subclass.

Comment: delete line `wvWebView.delegate = self` from viewcontroller and it should work

Comment: Ohh I see the mistake....

Comment: yup. Webview can't have two delegates, and you set it to the viewcontroller which doesn't (i assume) implement any of the delegate functions.